# Is there a Elseif limitation?

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am trying to write a code which will call different subtasks depending and a choice from a spreadsheet (and as it is using a different file as weel, making sure the right file has been chosen). 
We previously had that for 7 subs but I wanted to add a new one.

On meeting the conditions for the 8th one I always went to the `errhandler` line (else) and it never ran the `Sub8`. I checked the conditions were met using some `MsgBox` to make sure of it.

Is there some limitation I am missing? Is there something obvious I am missing?

Thanks for your help!

I used some message box to see where it was blocking but it seems it just won't read the last `elseif` I added. I tried to change some of the order but it did not work. 
I change the option 9 for 2 and it worked as expected so I am kind of lost here.

If you have any ideas that would be appreciated.

```
    If run_wb.Sheets(1).Range("Range") = "Option1" And Raw_wb.Names("template_type").RefersToRange = "suboption1" Then
        Call Sub 1

    ElseIf run_wb.Sheets(1).Range("Range") = " Option2" And Raw_wb.Names("template_type").RefersToRange = " suboption2" Then
        Call Sub 2

    ElseIf run_wb.Sheets(1).Range("Range") = " Option3" And Raw_wb.Names("template_type").RefersToRange = " suboption3" Then
        Call Sub3

    ElseIf run_wb.Sheets(1).Range("Range") = " Option4" And Raw_wb.Names("template_type").RefersToRange = " suboption4" Then
        Call Sub4

    ElseIf run_wb.Sheets(1).Range("Range") = " Option5" And Raw_wb.Names("template_type").RefersToRange = " suboption5" Then
        Call Sub5

    ElseIf run_wb.Sheets(1).Range("Range") = " Option6" And Raw_wb.Names("template_type").RefersToRange = " suboption6" Then
        Call Sub6

    ElseIf run_wb.Sheets(1).Range("Range") = " Option7" And Raw_wb.Names("template_type").RefersToRange = " suboption7" Then
        Call Sub6

    ElseIf run_wb.Sheets(1).Range("Range") = " Option8" And Raw_wb.Names("template_type").RefersToRange = "suoption8" Then
        Call Sub7

    ElseIf run_wb.Sheets(1).Range("Range") = " Option9" And Raw_wb.Names("template_type").RefersToRange = "suboption9" Then
        'Call Sub8
        MsgBox ("ok")

    Else
errhandler:
        MsgBox "The wrong template has been selected or this template cannot be used for data import. Please contact a system admin."
        Raw_wb.Close
    End If
```

Comment: You might look into using a `Switch` statement instead of lots of `ElseIf`s.

Comment: also `"suoption8"` might need to read `"suboption8"`

Answer (score 0):

There is no limitation on the number of `ElseIf` that can be used. I have code that will successfully step through 18 `ElseIf` statements. For more see the official documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/if-then-else-statement

Please see @Cyril's comment. It is your typo that is causing the error handler to catch.

Also you might want to look into cleaning up the preceding space that you have on a lot of the lines when there are quotation marks. It will make your code more consistent and cleaner.